# How to prevent ng-click from firing

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to create a directive that binds to the 'click' event on a button and prevents `ng-click` from firing if a condition is met.

I'm aware I can handle this within the `ng-click` directive itself e.g.

```
ng-click="vm.form.$valid && vm.savePost(vm.post)"
```

But my requirements are a little more complex than that.

I did create a directive than binds to the button's click event and calls `e.preventDefault()` but this did not stop `ng-click` from firing.

Comment: I usually create a custom "sumbit()" function to perform extra checks on an `ng-click` and then a function for `ng-disable` as well.

Comment: well, there is 100% way - indirective just store ngClick attr to variable, then set ngClick to empty value, then bind new function on click - if condition met launched stored function. Not beatiful solution thow (

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ngClick directive is fired first. In this case you can try to play with priority setting:

```
(function (module) {
    var myDirective = function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            priority: 1000,
            ........
        };
    };
    module.directive("myDirective", myDirective);
}(angular.module("module")));
```

From the official documentation for [compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

> priority
>
> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element,
>   sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives
>   are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their
>   compile functions get called.

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't prevent the ng-click handler from firing.

Answer (score 0):

I know that question is pretty old, however the directive below binds a click event handler which prevents the call of the function binded to ng-click on the same html element.

The keys are:

- `priority: -1`: since ngClick has a `priority: 0`, our directive's link (post-link) function will be executed after ngClick link function, as stated in [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-priority-):

> Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first.
>   Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link
>   functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the
>   same priority is undefined.

- `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` As stated in [JQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/):

> In addition to keeping any additional handlers on an element from
>   being executed, this method also stops the bubbling by implicitly
>   calling event.stopPropagation().

Directive code:

```
.directive('noClick', [function(){
        return {
            priority: -1,
            link: function(scope, iElem, iAttr){
                iElem.on('click', noClick);

                function noClick(e) {
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        };
    }])
```

HTML code

```
<div no-click ng-click="myFunct()">
```

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586231/angularjs-how-to-stop-event-propagation-from-ng-click/28586369#28586369)

Answer (score -1):

Prevent default is used to prevent normal action. For example  doesn't go to the target, or button doesn't submit and etc..

ng-click and onclick aren't default action and you can't prevent it with preventDefault.

You have to use function in ng-click, to make conditions before action.

Comment: Ofc, in general u can prevent ng-click.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov you can prevent onclick event with stopPropagation.